# Vinyl Plank Flooring Repair

Tags: vent, adhesive, vinyl-flooring, underlayment, saving-money

[image]

Questions

Flooring was already done before. Removed a drywall in the kitchen recently and leaving the floor unfinished.

1. Removing the whole plank and add a new one is better? Or patching is better? Patching has a concern that Adhesive must be used underneath because I'll not be able to lock it to other plank.
2. Does underlayment also has to match? Perge gold underlayment has been used before and its expensive. Can I use any other underlayment like roberts?
3. Also there is a AC/heater vent which is not really required. Can I use wood and caulk around to close it or use foilboard?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would try for a different colour/design, maybe even a different type of flooring like tile.  More of a design statement than a patch/match.  Unless one section is small enough to redo completely.

Comment: Its always goint to be obvious, so make it a feature.

Comment: @RohitGupta   Some typos do seem to make more sense.

Comment: Good luck finding matching planks, unless the installer left you some spares.